# ultrasonic phased array

Tags: signal-processing

I have the following code for Arduino mega to output 40 kHz square waves at the analog pins. I need to apply specific phase delays for the signals at each pin though and am struggling to find out how to do this. Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks!

```
byte TP = 0b10101010; // Every other port receives the inverted signal

void setup() {

DDRF = 0b11111111; // Set all analog ports to be outputs
DDRK = 0b11111111; // Set all analog ports to be outputs
// Initialize Timer1

noInterrupts(); // Disable interrupts

TCCR1A = 0;

TCCR1B = 0;

TCNT1 = 0;

OCR1A = 200; // Set compare register (16MHz / 200 = 80kHz square wave -> 40kHz full wave)

TCCR1B |= (1 << WGM12); // CTC mode

TCCR1B |= (1 << CS10); // Set prescaler to 1 ==> no prescaling

TIMSK1 |= (1 << OCIE1A); // Enable compare timer interrupt

interrupts(); // Enable interrupts

}

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect) {

PORTF = TP; // Send the value of TP to the outputs
PORTK = TP;
TP = ~TP; // Invert TP for the next run

}

void loop() {

// Nothing left to do here :)

}
```

Comment: Do you need multiple pins with linear growing phase delay?

Comment: Hi Chris :) I need multiple pins with different phase delays.

Comment: I suspect that you can't do that. The square wave output on AVR-based Arduinos is pretty crude, and relies on interrupt-driven counters and dividers to generate the outputs. I doubt if the hardware has enough precision to manage outputs with different phases. You might need to use external signal generator hardware for this.

Comment: hi Duncan :) thanks for the response. I am outputting the signals to the analog pins though not the PWM.

Comment: What phase delays do you need? Are they constant or variable? Will the program eventually grow and have something in `loop()` Could you use different pins?

Comment: I will calculate the phase delays in MATLAB depending on the desired focal point and apply the phases in the arduino code accordingly. yes it could have something in loop!  I could use different pins. open to suggestions. I have not used arduino before so am new to it :)